# Ayuda con definir una función en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Primero, que nada recién estoy empezando con `SQL SERVER` y estoy creando una función para poder cambiar el nombre de los días de inglés a español. Para lo cual he creado la función siguiente:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DIA_ESP(@DIAS VARCHAR)
   RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @DIA_ESPA VARCHAR
    SELECT @DIA_ESPA =
        CASE @DIAS
        WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN 'LUNES' WHEN 'TUESDAY' THEN 'MARTES' WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' THEN 'MIÉRCOLES'
        WHEN 'THURSDAY' THEN 'JUEVES' WHEN 'FRIDAY' THEN 'VIERNES' WHEN 'SATURDAY' THEN 'SÁBADO'
        WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN 'DOMINGO' ELSE NULL END   
    RETURN @DIA_ESPA
    END;
```

Pero al evaluarla me sale error.

```
dbo.DIA_ESP('SUNDAY');
```

```
# Message
# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 246
# Incorrect syntax near 'SUNDAY'.
```

Como recién estoy empezando no me doy cuenta en donde está mi error. Podrían ayudarme por favor y así poder corregir mi función.

Comment: Sin mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor. Ya deberías estar familiarizado con ello.

Comment: No me di cuenta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agrega la longitud del `varchar` en la definición de la función:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DIA_ESP(@DIAS VARCHAR(50))
       RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
    AS
        BEGIN
        DECLARE @DIA_ESPA VARCHAR(50)
        SELECT @DIA_ESPA =
            CASE @DIAS
            WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN 'LUNES' WHEN 'TUESDAY' THEN 'MARTES' WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' THEN 'MIÉRCOLES'
            WHEN 'THURSDAY' THEN 'JUEVES' WHEN 'FRIDAY' THEN 'VIERNES' WHEN 'SATURDAY' THEN 'SÁBADO'
            WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN 'DOMINGO' ELSE NULL END   
        RETURN @DIA_ESPA
        END;
```

Comment: Hola, sigue resultando lo mismo, me sale el mismo error.

Comment: Puedes agregar la consulta donde llamas a la función?

Comment: jajaja.. Perdón. tienes mucha razón. Error de novato. 

Ahora que lo corrigo, el resultado me sale sólo la `D`. ¿cómo hago para que me salga completo la palabra `DOMINGO`? por favor...

Comment: ya no es necesario, ya lo corregí. Muchas gracias.